# Quais os prós e contras de indexar vetores por zero ou por um?

Tags: array, característica-linguagem

A maioria das linguagens de programação que conheço tem `zero` como o primeiro índice de um vetor.

Eu sei que várias linguagens de programação têm o índice `um` como o primeiro índice de vetor. Até pouco tempo eu achava que isso se limitava a linguagens mais antigas (como COBOL, Fortran, Algol e Smalltalk), mas recentemente descobri que Lua e Matlab também começam seus *arrays* por `1`.

Eu acho que a decisão de índice inicial deve ser algo bastante sério. Que fatores os designers de linguagens consideram para determinar indexação base? Quais os prós e contras de cada forma?

Comment: Talvez, e esta é a minha opinião ( questão sinalizado ) , que foi originalmente pensado mais importante que um subscrito significou algo análogo ao leitor humano. Colocar algo no slot zero quando explicando é menos fácil de entender do que colocar algo em um slot . Compilador / interpretador faz algum trabalho de "traduzir" mas não é grande problema.

Comment: Eu quase consegui entender :D

Comment: @bigown Para os mais rapidos, eu uso Ingles. Com menos importancia de tempo, o meu proprio Portuguese fraco. Para respostas, uma mixtura de tempo, Google Translate, e ajuda de meu filho. Isto, so metodo fraco :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger não se preocupe, tem horas que seu texto fica muito mais fácil de entender do que os de alguns dos nossos "nativos". _don't worry, sometimes your text is easier to understand than some of our "native"'s_

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É possível enumerar vantagens e desvantagens de cada estilo de indexação. Mas sinceramente, se alguém disser que uma maneira é **muito** melhor e a outra é um **lixo**, essa pessoa é meio fanática... Afinal, até mesmo programadores C contam as linhas no seu editor de texto começando em 1 ;-)

Vamos aos exemplos:

**Vetor de 100 elementos, começando em 0 como em C, C++, Java ou Python e usando intervalos abertos no final como em Python (isto é, o último índice fica de fora):**

1. A declaração em C, C++, Java, etc. é `lista[100]` (indicando a **quantidade de elementos**), mas só dá para indexar até `lista[99]` (usar `lista[100]` igual ao que foi declarado seria um erro).
2. Portanto será necessário usar `size()-1` para **acessar o último elemento**.
3. **O acesso a subfaixas** do vetor é fácil. Se eu quisesse andar no vetor de 10 em 10 elementos, é só fazer 0*10, 1*10, 2*10, 3*10. Em Python fica assim: `lista[0:10]` inclui os primeiros 10 elementos, de 0 a 9; `lista[10:20]` inclui os elementos de 10 a 19; e `lista[20:30]` representa os elementos de 20 a 29. Repare que não foi necessário fazer nenhum “+1” nem “-1” e para obter o número de itens basta calcular `fim - início`.
4. O segundo elemento se chamará [1], o que é meio estranho. A melhor maneira de interpretar é pensar nos **índices como deslocamento**: lista[0] é o item do começo da lista, lista[1] é partir do começo e pular 1 (portanto o segundo elemento), lista[2] conta do começo e pula 2 (portanto chegando no terceiro elemento). Se a implementação de baixo nível fizer bom uso desse detalhe na implementação (como a dualidade de ponteiros e arrays em C), pode-se economizar uma instrução de máquina, deixando o código mais eficiente.
5. Se quiser **andar em círculos** nos primeiros 5 elementos, é possível incrementar o contador assim: `i = (i + 1) % 5`
6. Uma **faixa vazia** pode ser escrita como `lista[10:10]`.
7. Uma **faixa de um elemento** fica `lista[10:11]` (contém apenas o elemento lista[10])
8. Você precisará somar 1 para **exibir os índices** de uma lista ao usuário, pois é meio estranho começar uma lista com 0, a menos que seja um log para debugging. Também é estranho apresentar uma lista que termina em 9 mas não tem 9 elementos.
9. Um **índice inválido** pode ser representado com -1 (mas não com 0). Por exemplo, se uma busca não encontrar nenhum elemento, muitas funções em linguagens populares retornam -1 ou outro valor negativo. Python usa -1 para representar o último elemento, então o mais comum é jogar uma exceção quando uma busca não encontra nada.

**Vetor de 100 elementos, começando em 1, usando intervalos fechados (isto é, o último índice é incluído) como em Matlab:**

1. **O primeiro elemento** é 1 e intuitivamente **os índices são como números ordinais:** primeiro, segundo, terceiro...
2. **O último elemento** é 100 e **a quantidade de elementos** é igual ao último índice. Bem mais intuitivo e evita erros.
3. **O acesso a subfaixas** é um pouco mais complicado: `lista(1:10)`, `lista(11:20)`, `lista(21:30)`. Repare que é necessário usar 10 e 11, 20 e 21, 30 e 31, etc. Como esses valores provavelmente estarão em variáveis, o código fica com vários “+1” e/ou “-1”.
4. **A quantidade de elementos de uma subfaixa** é `fim - início + 1`. Por exemplo, de 11 a 20 existem 10 elementos, porque inclui as duas pontas, tanto o 11 quanto o 20.
5. Se quiser **andar em círculos** nos primeiros 5 elementos, a fórmula fica: `i = mod(i, 5) + 1` (agora, em vez do %, usei mod, já que estou usando Matlab como exemplo). Perceba que o “+1”, neste caso, fica fora do da operação mod, mas não é nem mais fácil nem mais difícil que indexando a partir de 0.
6. Uma **faixa vazia** (se suportada) poderia ser descrita como `lista(10:9)`.
7. Uma **faixa de um elemento** fica `lista(10:10)`.
8. Você pode **exibir os índices** diretamente ao usuário, pois a maioria das pessoas espera que uma lista seja numerada a partir de 1 (esta lista é assim).
9. Um **índice inválido** pode ser representado com 0. Por exemplo, se uma busca não encontrar nenhum elemento, retornar 0 para representar sua ausência pode ser bem intuitivo.

Note ainda que essas não são as únicas possibilidades. Eu combinei a indexação começando com 0 e as subfaixas com final aberto como em **Python**, mas em **VimScript** os índices começam em 0 e as subfaixas são `lista[0:9]`, `lista[10:19]`, `lista[20:29]`. Muita gente justifica o início de arrays com 0 baseado em subfaixas, mas isso mistura dois conceitos separados.

Ou então uma linguagem pode ter pouco ou nenhum suporte a subfaixas, o que diminui a importância algumas das características que eu listei acima. As vantagens das subfaixas são bem visíveis em Python, enquanto que a linguagem C, que não tem subfaixas, provavelmente foi criada indexando a partir de 0 por causa da aritmética de ponteiros. Afinal, se temos um ponteiro para o começo de um vetor, não precisamos fazer mais nada para acessar o primeiro item (já estamos nele, portanto o deslocamento é 0).

Outra curiosidade é o **Visual Basic**, em que uma declaração `lista(10)` é um vetor de 11 elementos, numerados de 0 a 10. Vantagem: a declaração contém um índice válido. Desvantagem: você precisa somar 1 mentalmente para saber o número de itens da lista.

Algumas linguagens permitem escolher qualquer faixa, como em **Fortran** ou **Pascal**. Por exemplo, em Pascal (ou Delphi) ficaria assim: `array[-10 .. 10] of integer`, o que permite usar arrays de um jeito bem criativo e bem adaptado ao problema a ser resolvido, pelo menos para arrays de tamanho fixo. Arrays dinâmicos são outra história e dependem do dialeto do Pascal — muitas vezes imitam a linguagem C e indexam a partir de 0 mesmo. Uma alternativa seria prover funções que retornem os limites do array.

Comment: Lembrei de mais uma situação interessante: funções de busca. Uma função de busca que não encontre um elemento pode retornar 0 se os índices começarem com 1, o que é interessante porque 0 pode ser associado à ausência do elemento. Caso 0 seja o índice do primeiro elemento, a função precisará retornar -1 ou indicar de outra maneira a falha na busca (exceção, retorno null, retorno None, etc.). Usar -1 pode ser inconveniente por não ser um valor associado com ausência nem com “false”, impedindo de usar a forma if (! find(...)).

Comment: Um artigo com um ponto de vista interessante, mostrando como a história da indexação por 0 pode ser facilmente esquecida e substituída por explicações “após o fato”: http://exple.tive.org/blarg/2013/10/22/citation-needed/

Answer (score 12):

Veja [essas notas](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF) do [Dijkstra](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_Dijkstra) que eu descaradamente [copiei do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c).

Basicamente a convenção ajuda a representar sequências sem ter que lidar com *corner cases*. Sabe aqueles códigos horríveis que possuem `ifs` para lidar com os limites inferiores e superiores? De quebra essa nota explica o motivo de existência de outra convenção: O porquê de incluirmos o limite inferior mas não o superior no intervalo de funções que lidam com índices (vide funções como *substring*; para obtermos os primeiros `n` caracteres de uma string geralmente fazemos algo como `string.substring(0,n)`).

---

Veja também [esse artigo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) na Wikipedia que enumera as seguintes vantagens:

1. Redução de [erros por um elemento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error)
2. Aritmética de ponteiros. O primeiro elemento de um array está na posição `0` - ou seja, em `ponteiro`, qualquer outro elemento está na posição `ponteiro + tamanho do elemento * índice`.
3. A questão de um sequência ser mais convenientemente representada por um intervalo aberto `[0, n)` do que por um intervalo fechado `[1, n]` conforme o artigo do Dijkstra.

Comment: Dado que numa lista de 100 elementos o último tem o índice 99 (e não 100), a redução de erros por um elemento é algo meio duvidoso; eles podem aumentar. A redução de erros só ocorre depois de pegar a prática, mas isso vale também para a indexação por 1 (e nela já temos prática desde a infância nas primeiras aulas de matemática ou até antes).

Comment: Oi @marcus, eu acho que o ponto do Dijkstra, bem como dos autores do artigo linkado é que indexação por 0 combinada com intervalo aberto costuma, em média, evitar erros por um, principalmente em lógicas de *slicing*. Pensando no seu exemplo, usar `0..100` com um intervalo aberto (`n < 100`) no término não resulta em nenhum problema. É possível, é claro, argumentar que `1..100` com intervalo fechado (`n <= 100`) seria similar. Dito isso, eu concordo com o seu ponto, usar `size - 1` para obter o último elemento pode ser bastante contraintuitivo. No fundo é questão de convenção / preferência.

Answer (score 5):

Bom, minha segunda sinalização rejeitada (de duas) :-)

Eu entendo que esse site possui regras diferentes do SO - e eu gostaria de aproveitar para dizer que esse site é meu favorito, por uma longa margem, dentre os sites da SE que eu visitei (que são mais do que podem ser vistos no meu perfil) - e talvez não seja tão bom comentar duma posição periférica. Essa é uma questão de opinião também :-)

OK, como resolver essa questão? Primeiro, pegar as quatro linguagens de idade que foram mencionadas, e identificar *por que* elas usaram "1" como ponto de partida (ao mesmo tempo, estabelecer qual, se alguma, possui "arrays" no sentido que eles são entendidos por muitos).

Então, pegar um punhado de linguagens, de preferência populares, e descobrir por que elas usam zero. Achar a linguagem mãe, onde deve haver uma relação óbvia.

Descobrir se algum dos dois conjuntos de respostas indicam um "agrupamento" de razão que por sua vez dê suporte à ideia de uma razão específica para esse traço.

Também descobrir para Lua e Mathematica (essa pode ser a parte mais fácil) por que eles usam um.

Juntar todos os resultados. Cogitar. Especular. Teorizar. Publicar.

Trabalho para um Historiador da Computação que especialize em Desenvolvimento de Linguagens.

---

#### Dijkstra

Um homem de opiniões, todas corretas de seu próprio ponto de vista. Porque para ele seu conhecimento é absoluto, e suas opiniões são fatos.

A man of opinions, every one of them correct to his own absolute certain knowledge.

Algumas citações das [notas](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF) citadas [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37043/498).

> I mention this experimental evidence - for what it is worth - because
> some people feel uncomfortable with conclusions that have not been
> confirmed in practice.

---

> Many programming languages have been designed without due attention to
> this detail [that we had better regard zero as a most natural number].

---

> [a mathematical colleague of mine] accused a number of younger
> computing scientists of "pedantry" because - as they do by habit -
> they started numbering at zero. He took consciously adopting the most
> sensible convention as a provocation.

---

Dijkstra escreve muito bem. É um prazer ler seus textos, não só pelo conteúdo mas também pelas pitadas de bom-humor.

Porém, afirmar que começar em zero é a única maneira de se fazer as coisas, e que qualquer outra opção não seria nem natural nem rigorosa é... uma afirmação, e parte do princípio de que tudo na sociedade (ou no trabalho), principalmente computação, deve ocorrer por meio do rigor, e levar a alguma conclusão natural que não possa ser contestada.

**As coisas não funcionam assim.**

Acho que Dijkstra adoraria entrar num elevador e ver um botão `Piso 0`. Ele talvez se recusasse a entrar num elevador que usasse `T` para o térreo ou `1` como o último andar antes da garagem.

Na verdade, eu gosto dessa ideia. Imagine o Dijkstra apertando zero e indo para na garagem. Ele volta para o elevador e aperta o zero de novo. Garagem outra vez. Ele iria escrever bem sobre isso, dizendo que o problema é do projeto do prédio. OK. Isso é só a minha opinião e a minha imaginação.

Abra uma gaveta de arquivos. Veja as pastas lá dentro. Se alguém diz "primeira", "última", "terceira a partir do fundo", "aquela ao lado da vermelha" ou algo assim, conseguimos encontrar o que procuramos, independentemente de contarmos do zero ou do um. Pode até ser que precisemos olhar o conteúdo de duas pastas para encontrar, mas vai dar certo se a informação que nos deram estiver correta.

#### Isso importa?

O processador da linguagem lida com tudo de qualquer forma. Não importa o que nós escrevemos (desde que apropriado para aquela linguagem), o processador da linguagem vai fazer o que ele tem de fazer. Em muitos exemplos não há mais um significado nem mesmo em si própria. Um array associativo *não começa* com zero, ou um. Hoje há muitas "construções de loop" que não têm de especificar um valor inicial, porque quando você pensa sobre isso, é razoável esperar de uma linguagem de nível mais alto que "eu gostaria de consultar todos os valores dessa coisa, compilador favor começar no lugar certo" funcione como esperado.

---

Não, eu não vou gastar mais esforço nessa pergunta do que ela vale, sinto muito. Eu a marquei como CW, já que essas são algumas reações a opiniões, em uma pergunta opinativa, que não pode ser respondida de outra forma senão com incertezas, eu certamente não quero nenhuma reputação por isso, ainda que alguém a julgue merecedora.

É uma pergunta para um bar na praia, pra quando você está preso num elevador com alguns programadores, ou para seus sonhos, quando você vence o debate e todo o mundo (da programação) concorda com você.

---

Posição Inicial 1 = Deslocamento 0

COBOL, aquela linguagem que está aí há um tempo e que talvez poucos entendam, não possui "arrays", mas ela tem "tabelas" com `OCCURS`.

```
01  A-TABLE.
    05  FILLER OCCURS 100 TIMES
        INDEXED BY AN-INDEX-NAME.
        10  SOME-DATA             PIC XX.
```

Para referenciar uma entrada na tabela, subscrevendo, você pode usar o índice data-item AN-INDEX-NAME ou usar um literal ou usar um data-name (somente inteiros, mas nós não temos "ints" dessa forma).

A maneira mais rápida de acessar um elemento é com um literal, porque o compilador calcula o deslocamento. O literal 1 ganha o deslocamento 0. O literal 2 ganha ((2-1) * tamanho do elemento) etc.

O índice data-item você atribui (SET) a um valor. Você faz SET ... TO 1 e o compilador usa um valor zero. Você usa SET ... TO 2 e o compilador usa ((2-1) * tamanho do elemento) etc. Você pode fazer SET ... UP ou SET ... DOWN e o compilador adiciona ou subtrai o tamanho do elemento de forma apropriada.

Usando um índice data-item é a segunda maneira mais rápida. Na maior parte do tempo.

Usando um data-item como subscrito, o compilador precisa gerar código para "converter" o valor para um deslocamento. Um pouco mais de trabalho. Sempre um data-name para subscrever com um valor de 1 será calculado para um deslocamento de 0.

Exceto. Para o caso especial, onde o tamanho do elemento é um.

Nesse caso, o compilador irá usar o valor de data-name diretamente, ele vai apenas "fingir" que a tabela começa um byte antes. Nesse caso especial, o data-name-for-a-subscript é *mais rápido* que usando o índice data-item.

Nós humanos sempre usamos 1 para a primeira entrada de uma tabela. O compilador usa 0, ou modifica sua implementação de 0 no caso especial de uma tabela com entradas de um único byte e usa 1 para a primeira entrada.

Agora, a situação é, com COBOL, nossas tabelas têm tamanho fixo. Nós precisamos saber quantas entradas existem na tabela, quais são de fato usadas. O compilador não pode nos dizer. Se nós temos que saber quantas são, nós temos que saber que é 0 quando não há nenhuma entrada. Se nós tivéssemos que subscrever de zero, nós teríamos um teste interessante para ver se nós excedemos o número de entradas em uma tabela.

Meu palpite seria que o exposto acima não é a razão pela qual a subscrição "começa" de um no design, mas que o design decidiu, porque o objetivo da linguagem era tornar mais fácil para humanos programarem, que começar por um era um conceito mais fácil de pegar o jeito (naquele estágio da história da computação).

Para conseguir uma base para um ou outro ponto, você provavelmente teria que dar uma olhada na linguagem FLOWMATIC, em que muito do design da mesma foi usada para COBOL.

Possíveltalvezquemsabe não foi nem uma decisão consciente mas algo tão "óbvio" que nem foi muito discutido.

Entretanto, é improvável que qualquer um vivo saiba a resposta para COBOL. Ou FORTRAN. Ou ALGOL. SMALLTALK é um pouco mais novo. Talvez uma resposta possa ser encontrada observando todas as notas de design de COBOL. Talvez não.

É uma pergunta apenas de especulação e opinião, e do modo que eu vejo não há uma resposta "certa" ou "errada" a por que essas linguagens dessa época fizeram assim.

Dijkstra, que parece achar que todos `<ol><li>` deveriam começar em 0, certamente não sabia.

> Resposta traduzida livremente do original em inglês, no histórico de revisões.

Comment: Most people don't ever intend to design new programming languages. But some of us do, myself included. For us, this is a very relevant question, even if the answer turns out to be "a matter of preference" (it's not: computers are as happy consuming binary code, but programs are written by humans). I wouldn't ask every question about language design here at StackOverflow (most would be more appropriate in a platform like Discourse), but a selected few are sure answerable objectively (I have strong subjective reasons to shun 1-based indices, but they don't fit this site so I'm keeping to myself)

Comment: @mgibsonbr fair enough, but I don't see something like this as a good starting-point for even approaching the question over 1/0, let alone answering it. I think a language could be designed without the programmer having to *know*, and that would deal with a lot of "off by one" problems. To design a new language for todays' new programmers, I think you have to research pretty-much in modern times. I don't think the past will tell you whether 0 or 1 is "right" or "wrong", just how they were used in a given particular language. Implementation detail.

Comment: Agreed. In fact, one very good reason to choose between one or another is how well it integrates with other programs - potentially written in different languagues (most of them contemporary). BTW: IMHO the answer got a lot better after the edit (those facts about the reasoning behind COBOL implementations are very insightful), so I retracted my downvote.

Comment: @mgibsonbr no problem, although I was thinking of avoiding benefits if anyone wanted to upvote, I also get protected from the downvotes (didn't think of that). Inter-language communication? Very interesting. Can't discuss it here though :-)

Comment: @mgibsonbr and just a point, those are facts about how COBOL (on IBM Mainframes) is *implemented* (for the one-byte table especially, the rest is fairly general). I deliberately avoided rationalising, reading history backwards, to say why COBOL had 1 when it came into being.

Comment: So... who's going to translate this to Portuguese? :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, I think quoting Dijkstra just got me going (coming as it did after the allusion that COBOL is a pre-Christian-era language). A bit of a non-answer, I have to admit. If there is interest I can do a little work on it, but I'm not sure how helpful it is to the discussion (which shouldn't be happening in this format....).

Comment: Regarding the question, this is answerable: *Que fatores os designers de linguagens consideram para determinar indexação base? Quais os prós e contras de cada forma?* Of course there is no right answer to "which is better", but that's not what's being asked. Note: your flag was rejected from the review queue (3 "leave open" votes). Had a mod handled it, it would probably be marked *helpful*.

Comment: @bfavaretto "So... who's going to translate this to Portuguese?" There is goes... Hopefully I didn't mess up the COBOL part. Only left the Dijkstra quote as it is, since I couldn't figure out its exact meaning ("correto com certeza absoluta, pelo menos até onde vai seu conhecimento"? "correto de acordo com seu conhecimento, que é certo e absoluto"? etc)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu também não sei traduzir a citação, tive a mesma dúvida. Bill, você pode explicar o significado pra gente?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Muito obrigado. Sorry about the continuation...

Comment: @bfavaretto more difficult than I thought.