# Por que Arrays começam em 0 e não em 1

Tags: java, array

Por que arrays começam em 0 e não em 1 ?

Não existe 0 pessoas, 0 animais, 0 nada...(não se apeguem a esta parte)

Qual o intuito de fazer isto? Acredito que não deve ser só eu que não entende a lógica disto, se é que tem.

Comment: Porque o que começa em zero sáo os indices, o tamanho do array ainda é contavel da mesma forma.

Comment: Porque 0 vem antes de 1

Comment: A pergunta já foi respondida, e muito bem aliás. Porém deixo aqui um á parte, quando você refere  `Não existe 0 pessoas, 0 animais, 0 nada.` você está ***quantificar*** algo, quando na verdade o que pretendemos aqui é indicar a ***posição*** de algo em um array.

Comment: `(não se apeguem a esta parte)` oopps

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que tem de ser colocado o '-1' logo depois de uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184760/5878)

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais os prós e contras de indexar vetores por zero ou por um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37029/5878)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Um array é um conjunto de elementos dispostos lado-a-lado na memória, a partir de um endereço.

Por exemplo, digamos que na memória você tenha 10 inteiros, num array. E que o endereço desse array na memória seja o 100 (número este escolhido pelo SO, que encontrou uma área de memória livre para o array).

Como cada inteiro tem 4 bytes, o primeiro elemento estará no próprio índice 100, o segundo no índice 104, o terceiro no índice 108, e assim por diante.

Como se calcula a posição de memória do elemento de maneira genérica? Veja:

```
Primeiro elemento: 0 * 4 bytes + 100 bytes
Segundo elemento: 1 * 4 bytes + 100 bytes
Terceiro elemento: 2 * 4 bytes + 100 bytes.
```

Olhando os cálculos, fica fácil ver porque convencionou-se que o índice seria baseado em 0, não em 1. Assim, não seria necessário subtrair 1 caso um cálculo desse tipo tivesse que ser feito (e nas primeiras linguagens, era muito comum que cálculos assim fossem feitos, pois se manipulava muita memória na mão). E mesmo para um compilador, seria mais fácil fazer a conversão.

Outra razão é que na matemática (e as primeiras aplicações eram muito matemáticas) é muito comum usar elementos baseados em 0.

Note que isso é apenas uma convenção. Não há uma razão técnica em termos de desempenho ou gasto de memória que a justifique. Alguns compiladores antigos tinham índices baseados em 1, ou até mesmo configuráveis (como é o caso do Pascal, linguagem anterior ao C). Não há perda de bits ou desempenho, pois o compilador é capaz de fazer a subtração desse índice em tempo de compilação, mas usar um índice baseado em 0 era muito prático e essa convenção se mantém até hoje.

Comment: Boa resposta. Você teria algumas, boas, fontes/referências para eu estudar mais a fundo?

Comment: Valdeir eu li este [Livro](https://www.amazon.com.br/Artigos-T%C3%A9cnicos-Omero-Francisco-Bertol/dp/853990666X?tag=goog0ef-20&smid=A1ZZFT5FULY4LN&ascsubtag=98dc83bc-48b8-4ab5-947d-b98ee706de1f) e recomendo se possível que leia.

Comment: Herança do C, também. Tem vários motivos para isso, inclusive ficar mais próximo do hardware (não se esqueça, C é assembly estruturado)

Answer (score 1):

Esta resposta deveria ser um comentário. Uma resposta em inglês para sua pergunta se encontra em: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

Meu comentário é que você está confundindo o número ordinal zero (na linguística) com o numero cardinal zero. O índice de um array não designa uma quantidade (não é um número cardinal), mas sim uma posição em uma sequência. No cotidiano, é mais comum indexar uma ordenação começando pelo 'primeiro' elemento, seguido pelo 'segundo' e assim por diante. Mas, como tanto os números cardinais quanto os ordinais generalizam os números naturais, ambos incluem o zero, sendo perfeitamente possível indexar uma ordenação começando pelo "[zero-ésimo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0th)" elemento, a menor posição na sequência.

Comment: Esse seu "comentário" me pareceu bastante relevante como "resposta". E muito obrigado por lembrar da diferença entre ordinais e cardinais, eu mesmo vivo trocando ambos quando não estou ativamente pensando no assunto

Answer (score -4):

Simplesmente porque os algarismo decimais são 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 e 9, não 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 e 10 como comumente contamos (de forma errônea).

Comment: Então o que diria neste caso: `lista[-1]`

Comment: Computador usa algarismos binários, então deveria ter apenas 0 e 1? Talvez você estivesse se referindo aos números naturais, que podem ou não começar em 0, depende muito do sistema axiomático que você está usando