# Como filtrar as colunas da minha tabela por dados que comecem só por números?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, postgresql, mysqli

Por exemplo:
Eu tenho uma tabela com dados assim

| id | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 Estação Cursos_Link |
| 2 | Estação Palestras Banco de dados |
| 3 | 1.3 Estação Cusos_WhatsApp |

Eu queria filtrar minha coluna nome só com os dados que comecem com números, como proceder?

Usei o seguinte código abaixo mas não deu certo.

```
SELECT nome FROM [ODS_Tabela_cursos] WHERE nome = '1.'
```

Tentativa:

```
SELECT nome FROM [ODS_Tabela_cursos] WHERE nome = '1.'
```

Espero filtrar a coluna só pegando os itens que comece por números

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando uma composição de funções, utilizando a função [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) com [isnumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

A função `substring` vai "recortar" a string nome, e vai retornar o caractere de índice zero da coluna nome.

Após o recorte verificamos com a função `isnumeric` se este caractere é numérico.

> ISNUMERIC retorna 1 quando a expressão de entrada é avaliada como um tipo de dados numérico válido; caso contrário, retorna 0.

Compondo as funções, temos a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(nome,1,1)) = 1;
```

Para resultados mais robustos recomendo utilizar uma função [trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) para remover qualquer espaço em branco incluído acidentalmente na string nome.

```
SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(TRIM(nome),1,1)) = 1;
```

Repare que a função `substring` [possui indexação baseada em 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37056/103217), então se quer o primeiro caractere devemos passar o valor 1.